# Keeping some array elements fixed in R

Tags: arrays, r

I'm sure this is a fairly straightforward question but I'm not sure how to do this. I have given an example array with dimensions (4,4,5) as follows:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    5    0
[2,]    0   NA    0    6
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    10   0
[2,]    0   NA    0    12
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    15   0
[2,]    0   NA    0    18
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    20   0
[2,]    0   NA    0    24
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    25   0
[2,]    0   NA    0    30
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

Basically, for this example array I'd like the elements at [1,3] and [2,4] to change along the 3rd dimension but I'm not sure how to write this code in R. I've tried using variations of the code `array(c(1,0,0,0,0,NA,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,6,0,0), dim=c(4,4,3))` and I tried checking online but I can't seem to find anything which helps with this issue, so any help I can get would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share data using `dput` and also show expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah I don't really have any `dput` output because I have no idea how to even code it up :( The expected output is what I have given in the post above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure on your expected output, but perhaps something like this using a `for` loop?

```
arr <- array(c(1,0,0,0,0,NA,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,6,0,0), dim=c(4,4,3))

for (i in seq_len(dim(arr)[3])) {
    arr[1, 3, i] <- 100;       # Change entry (1, 3) of every 2d matrix 
    arr[2, 4, i] <- 100;       # Change entry (2, 4) of every 2d matrix
}
arr
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0  100    0
#[2,]    0   NA    0  100
#[3,]    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0  100    0
#[2,]    0   NA    0  100
#[3,]    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0
#
#, , 3
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0  100    0
#[2,]    0   NA    0  100
#[3,]    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

---

As pointed out by @Cole, in this (simple) case there's no need for a `for` loop

```
arr[1, 3, ] <- 100
arr[2, 4, ] <- 100
```

is much faster than.

Comment: This seems like it does what I want, but is there a faster way to do it besides a `for` loop? The data I'm working with is quite large unfortunately :/

Comment: @ThePlowKing It's a misconception that `for` loops are intrinsically slow in R. In this case, we're overwriting values which is fast. It's when you misuse`for` loops to grow R objects dynamically when things go bad. If this is really too slow, you may have to look into non base R options, e.g. using `Rcpp`.

Comment: There should be no need for the loop. ```arr[1, 3, ] <- 100``` will provide the same result as ```for (i in...) { arr[1,3,i] <- 100}``` - removing the loop makes this answer 1000 times faster and about 3 times faster than @thelatemail

Comment: @Cole - that's definitely a good point, but you'd still have to do assignments for each of `arr[1,3,]` and `arr[2,4,]` etc. If you have a small number of row/col combos to overwrite, your suggestion will be super fast. I'm not sure how to generalise that to many indexes though.

Comment: I'm not sure ```arr[cbind(c(1,2),c(3,4),rep(...)``` saves much typing either. But as your answer suggests, if OP had a rule of which elements to update, your answer would accommodate a rule much quicker than ```arr[1,3, ] <- 100```. It's easy to imagine ```cbind(1:3, 4:6, rep(...)```. I'm adding a third answer because why not ```arr[arr > 4] <- 100```.

Comment: @Cole Been away for an hour at a meeting, and missed the follow-up; thanks to all for the interesting updates and suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with one assignment too using matrix indexing:

```
arr[cbind(c(1,2),c(3,4),rep(seq_len(dim(arr)[[3]]), each=2))] <- c(80,100)
arr
#, , 1
# 
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0   80    0
#[2,]    0   NA    0  100
#[3,]    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0
# 
#, , 2
#
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0   80    0
#[2,]    0   NA    0  100
#[3,]    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0
# 
#, , 3
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0   80    0
#[2,]    0   NA    0  100
#[3,]    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

The part inside `[]` gives the indexes `row/col/strata` for each value to replace:

```
cbind(c(1,2),c(3,4),rep(seq_len(dim(arr)[[3]]), each=2))
#     row  col  strata
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    3    1
#[2,]    2    4    1
#[3,]    1    3    2
#[4,]    2    4    2
#[5,]    1    3    3
#[6,]    2    4    3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're updating based on values, you apply a condition:

```
arr[arr > 4 ] <- 100
```

What's happening is that the inside `arr > 4` is generating an array:

```
, , 1

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE    NA FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

, , 2

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE    NA FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

, , 3

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE    NA FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

And then we're just saying assign a value to the conditions which are true. We can also use `which(arr > 4, arr.ind = T)` to return a matrix similar to @thelatemail's solution without the typing. This allows us to get to your original post answer:

```
which_cond <- which(arr>4, arr.ind = T) 
arr[which_cond] <- arr[which_cond] * which_cond[, 3]
arr
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    5    0
[2,]    0   NA    0    6
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0   10    0
[2,]    0   NA    0   12
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0   15    0
[2,]    0   NA    0   18
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

which_cond
     dim1 dim2 dim3
[1,]    1    3    1
[2,]    2    4    1
[3,]    1    3    2
[4,]    2    4    2
[5,]    1    3    3
[6,]    2    4    3
```

Performance:

```
#4x4x3 array
Unit: microseconds
                 expr    min      lq    mean  median      uq    max neval
        maur_improved    2.4    3.55    5.42    4.90    5.95   24.4   100
 latemail_all_at_once    6.4    8.70   14.00   15.20   18.40   25.3   100
        maur_for_loop 3280.0 3510.00 3810.00 3630.00 3770.00 6430.0   100
      cole_subset_mat    2.0    3.05    4.71    4.05    6.50   10.2   100
           cole_which   27.9   34.50   47.70   45.40   54.80  228.0   100

#4x4x3E6 array
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr   min    lq  mean median    uq  max neval
        maur_improved  82.9  84.8  89.7   85.8  87.4  165   100
 latemail_all_at_once 347.0 361.0 391.0  378.0 417.0  564   100
        maur_for_loop 422.0 432.0 462.0  451.0 486.0  721   100
      cole_subset_mat 304.0 330.0 369.0  354.0 395.0  527   100
           cole_which 783.0 842.0 899.0  878.0 928.0 1370   100
```

And code:

```
arr <- array(c(1,0,0,0,0,NA,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,6,0,0), dim=c(4,4,3))

library(microbenchmark)

x = microbenchmark(
  maur_improved = {
    arr[1,3, ] <- 100
    arr[2, 4, ] <- 100
  },
  latemail_all_at_once = {
    arr[cbind(c(1,2),c(3,4),rep(seq_len(dim(arr)[[3]]), each=2))] <- c(80,100)
  },
  maur_for_loop = {
    for (i in seq_len(dim(arr)[3])) {
      arr[1, 3, i] <- 100;       # Change entry (1, 3) of every 2d matrix 
      arr[2, 4, i] <- 100;       # Change entry (2, 4) of every 2d matrix
    }
  },
  cole_subset_mat = {
    arr[arr > 4] <- 100
  }
  , cole_which = {
    which_cond <- which(arr>4, arr.ind = T) 
    arr[which_cond] <- arr[which_cond] * which_cond[, 3]
  }
)
print(x, signif = 3)
```

Comment: It's worth noting in these benchmarks that a microsecond is absolutely tiny. Even with 2 million array groups the difference between the fastest and slowest is only 0.2 seconds by my testing.

Comment: The overhead for the ```for``` loop appears to be a one time hit. Good call on bringing this up - but I'm still amazed that R can update 3 million arrays in less than 90 ms. I'll be more careful about timings on such small dataset as microseconds are near meaningless.